# UNNotificationServiceExtension - notifications stop presenting?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Experimenting with new UNNotificationServiceExtension and notice interesting behaviour.

Start testing today in Xcode around 9:00 and notifications seems to flow. Content was modified and everything was fine.

In 13:30 all notifications just stop presenting for all of my apps(I'm  testing with more than one app from same team). I've send maybe 100 pushes for couple of hours (Normal behaviour when debugging, I will **never** do this at production,because of the limits of APNS.)

I'm testing on one device (iPhone 5S) and when testing on other device (iPhone 6) content was modified.
Also if remove "mutable-content" key notifications start showing up again

So is there a limitation for sending pushes, even if you we debug application?
Is anyone have similar issues?

Here is code of extension.It is almost same as template:

```
@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    self.bestAttemptContent.body = @"Modified content";
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}
```

And here is code of App delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
   requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert|UNAuthorizationOptionSound|UNAuthorizationOptionBadge)
   completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     if (granted) {
       [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
     }
   }];

  return YES;
}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  NSLog(@"Token %@",deviceToken);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
}
```

It is very simple and dummy code with no additional calculations.

For a push sending I'm using javapns library like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> finalContent = ...
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(finalContent);
PushNotificationBigPayload payload = PushNotificationBigPayload.fromJSON(object.toString());

List<PushedNotification> notifications = new ArrayList<PushedNotification>();
try {
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    tokens.add("token ....");
    notifications = Push.payload(payload,
            "*.p12", "12345",
            false, tokens);
    for(PushedNotification notification : notifications){
        System.out.println(notification);
    }

} catch (CommunicationException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} catch (KeystoreException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

**EDIT**: After device reboot, notfications modify content again.

Comment: In my testing, I have noted within the console output that my test device displays a cryptic note suggesting it has received a "completely unknown token" and thus re-routes it device-scoped and not app-scoped and the app never sees it. Not sure if your situation is similar. I dropped a radar for this issue because it is rectified by simply wiping the app itself, and re-running debug to install. I real pain as i repeated have to so a minor setup in the app.

Radar: 28789788

Hope this helps..